# critical value set is noncompact

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

From Sard's theorem, we know that the critical value of smooth "enough" function must be of measure zero. But this does not exclude the case of noncompactness. My question is: is there any smooth function with noncompact critical value set? What about real analytic function? What about real subanalytic function?

Answer (score 0):

Let $f(x) = \sin(x)+ x/2$. This real analytic function has unbounded and hence non-compact critical set.